# Please tell me what is the error in this sql query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.catid
     , b.catname
     , a.details
     , a.debit
     , a.credit
     , a.balance
  FROM manual_update a
 WHERE catid IN(SELECT catid FROM category) b 
 WHERE a.catid = b.catid 
   AND a.month = 'July' 
   AND a.year ='2005' 
    OR a.balance = ''
```

Comment: You have two `where` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The query has more than one

```
where
```

keyword.

Correct query should be like this:

```
SELECT a.catid,b.catname,a.details,a.debit,a.credit,a.balance
FROM manual_update a
WHERE a.catid IN(SELECT catid FROM category) b AND a.catid=b.catid AND
a.month='July' AND a.year ='2005' OR a.balance = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a join between category and manual_update.

```
SELECT a.catid
 , b.catname
 , a.details
 , a.debit
 , a.credit
FROM manual_update a
INNER JOIN category b 
    ON b.catid = a.catid
WHERE a.month = 'July' 
    AND a.year ='2005' 
    OR a.balance = ''
```

you can try with this sqlfiddle (there isn't data but you can add them if you want) :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/208cd/5/0